# How does the counter in this recursion program increase from 0-9? Please help me understand

Tags: java

```
public class counter {
static void myMethod(int counter)
{
    if(counter==0)
    {return;}
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Hello "+counter);
        myMethod(--counter);
        System.out.print(" "+counter);
        
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    myMethod(10);
}}
```

> Output : Here after printing ("Hello "+counter) from 10 to 0, o/p goes again from 0 to 9 the latter is what I don't understand

Output:
Hello 10
Hello 9
Hello 8
Hello 7
Hello 6
Hello 5
Hello 4
Hello 3
Hello 2
Hello 1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Comment: What do you expect instead? Try running the program with pen and paper.

Comment: yes but what I don't understand why it increments from 0 to 9 after it prints " Hello counter "

Comment: Recursion can be confusing to follow, as one method is printing one thing while the method it called (the same method with a different variable) is printing something else. However, as your code is now, it should never make it to 9 as you are starting with 2 and decrementing to 0. Are you sure this is the entirety of the code? If you called myMethod with 10 then it would make sense.

Comment: @dbrewster Sorry... actually I forgot to change the method parameter from 2 to 10 in the main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I'll take a stab on explaining this. I am going to name the following 3 lines for the sake of simplicity.

```
    1    System.out.print("Hello "+counter);
    2    myMethod(--counter);
    3    System.out.print(" "+counter);
```

and I will name each method call a letter of the alphabet

so we start with

1. A1 - Prints "Hello 10"
2. A2 - calls method B -> B1 - Prints "Hello 9"
3. B2 - calls method C -> C1 - Prints "Hello 8"

etc

9. G1 Prints "Hello 1"
10. G2 - calls new method H with variable 0 and this marks the end of G2
11. G3 Prints "1". That marks the completion of method G which means method F can now move on to line 3 so
12. F3 Prints "2".
    etc

Line 2 for Method A is only completed after all of those other methods complete. So only then does it move on to line 3 which is Print counter. Remember, the counter for method A was equal to 10, and then it decremented by 1 to 9 on line 2. Thus it prints "9" even though the other methods have further decremented the counter to 0 as method A's variable is function scoped and thus is not affected by the other methods.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but you don't understand my question... I already understand that it is supposed to print the following (Hello 10 Hello 9 Hello 8 Hello 7 Hello 6 Hello 5 Hello4 Hello 3 Hello 2 Hello1 ) but after that it goes on to print the following(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)... I understand the output from the first two statements you mentioned here out of the three, not the third statement... try it out yourself

Comment: @Ghostpepper.Wasabi Steps 10-12 and the paragraph at the end should answer that question. I am guessing you read my answer before I edited it because originally it was unclear but I believe my explanation is sufficient now. Let me know if you still don't understand

Comment: Thank you I understand it now, you meant to say that when Method call G1 completes
printing  (hello1), G3 prints(1), before which F1 printed(hello2), then F3 goes on to print(2), before which E1 printed (hello3), then E3 prints(3)...etc

Comment: Right. This happens in regular methods as well. If method A calls method B on line 2, it won't move on to line 3 until after method B has completed.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `myMethod(10)`, it will do the followings:

1. Print "Hello 10"
2. invoke `myMethod(9)`
3. Print "9"

When you invoke `myMethod(9)`, it will do the followings:

1. Print "Hello 9"
2. invoke `myMethod(8)`
3. Print "8"

Replace the invocation of `myMethod(9)` in the first list (line 2.), you get:

1. Print "Hello 10"
2. Print "Hello 9"
3. invoke `myMethod(8)`
4. Print "8"
5. Print "9"

Etc... until `myMethod(0)` that doesn't do anything

Comment: How about now? I updated the question with the actual output I am getting.

Comment: What I am pointing at... is that when the o/p reaches "Hello 1" , then then code prints 0 through 9... I don't understand why it increments

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me now, thank you for your help.